# When spelling, when to say 'double xx' and when 'x x'

Tags: spelling-pronunciations

This is something I have been wondering for a long time. When you spell (out loud) words that have some consonants doubled, you can say those as "double-X", or not (e.g. *Allan*: "Ay double-ell ay en" vs. "Ay ell ell ay en").

What interests me is, is there any sort of rule as to when to use the "double-X" and when to simply pronounce the letter twice?

This question also creates a personal dilemma: how to spell my own last name.  :) It is a Balkans name, "Bolla", and I personally always used spelling: "bee oh double-ell ay". No one ever told me it was bad, yet is it better than: "bee oh ell ell ay"?

Thanks in advance, i do not know any native speakers and I don't get to speak English that often to find answer anywhere but on the internet. :)

Comment: Either is fine; but when required to spell my name aloud I have taken to spelling it "Delta Oscar November Oscar Victor Alpha November"--that is, according to the [NATO system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet). Yours would be "Bravo Oscar Lima Lima Alpha." So many letter names rhyme or near-rhyme in English that confusion is all too easy otherwise, though some might be slightly disturbed by the military flavor.

Comment: You can use it anytime. **Except** that *double u* is not clear. ;-)

Comment: @Drew And also excepting that _oh oh seven_ is never acceptable and will, in fact, get you summarily deported. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yes, one double-ought not even say double-ought seven.

Comment: Never, unless you're talking about wire gauges or unless it makes it memorable like in a phone number: e.g., triple seven, one one, zero six. 'double one' would be confusing with *or* without "triple seven" and even adds a syllable (*double [anything]* doesn't improve clarity or make it more concise, so why would you?). Triple seven uses 2 less syllables then 7,7,7. Where as double one (or 'ell') *adds* a syllable. I agree with Brian, for absolute clarity use the phonetic alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

> What interests me is, is there any sort of rule as to when to use the "double-X" and when to simply pronounce the letter twice?

There is no firm rule; I think both ways are correct in all cases.

That said, I think the "double __" form is not very commonly used for vowels (except in initialisms, as [Chris Phan](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/13034/chris-phan) notes in a comment below). I think this is because, unlike (for example) <p> vs. <pp>, where both are pronounced /p/ (though they can affect the pronunciation of a preceding vowel), doubled vowels are usually pronounced differently: <red> and <reed>, or <cop> and <coop>, for example. I wouldn't generally say that <reed> has a "double E" or that <coop> has a "double O".

And for a different reason, I'd be unlikely to say that *vacuum* has a "double U"!

Comment: Spell *continuum* to someone who doesn't know the word, see what happens.

Comment: "Double-A" is sometimes used when spelling out an initialism, such as NCAA ("N-C-double-A") or NAACP ("N-double-A-C-P").

Comment: @ChrisPhan: Oh, good point. Also AAA ("triple-A").